# Criar ficheiro vCard (.vcf)

Tags: php

Quero criar um ficheiro vCard em PHP. Inserir valores que vem de uma base de dados SQLite, e fazer o download do ficheiro.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas questões diferentes:

1. Listar os dados de um banco de dados SQLite
2. Gerar o vCard

O primeiro problema é simples, basta usar a [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) ou a [SQLite](http://php.net/sqlite). Basta conectar, executar a query e ler o recurso. Isso é básico e muda pouca coisa de um SGBD para outro.

Para o segundo problema você tem que estudar [a especificação](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) do formato vCard, o que é bem difícil como toda RFC, criar o vCard manualmente a partir de um [exemplo mais legível](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Example_vCard_files) ou terceirizar.

Existem diversas classes prontas para criação de vCards. Umas mais completas que outras e outras mais que dão conta do básico. Uma pesquisa rápida no Google e você encontraria, por exemplo, [esse artigo](http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_vcard/) com uma classe de fácil uso:

```
require 'vCard.class.php'; // Altere se necessário

$vCard = new vcard;

$vCard -> data['first_name'] = 'Bruno Augusto';

$vCard -> download();
```

Eu preenchi apenas meu nome porque sou preguiçoso. :p

O método **download** como o nome sugere vai forçar o download do arquivo VCF pronto. Talvez você precise de um leitor de VCF. Aqui o Windows 7 reconheceu automaticamente:

[image: vCard]

Comment: Tens um _Parse error_ no teu código ;)

Comment: O Sublime enche as paciências fechando os colchetes dos meus arrays automaticamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Sempre às ordens e +1 pela resposta.